# Winding Tefillin Strap Around Middle Finger

Tags: halacha, history, tefilin

I was taught that one wraps the tefillin around his middle finger three times. Once between the top half of the finger, and twice around the bottom half of the finger.

However I ran across an article about tefillin put out by a Spanish Portuguese community. The article says the following:

*Note: A minor additional point is that the index finger windings were originally one winding round each section of the finger (lower picture), until Ben Ish Hai changed it to one around the middle and two around the lower section (upper picture).*

Source: https://sites.google.com/site/londonsephardiminhag/tephillin

Is there any sources to confirm the assertion that originally we are to wrap around the top middle and bottom parts of the finger?

Comment: I would contact R' Cohen. I strongly suspect that this was a typo, on his part, as he shows the S&P style kerichot without a single wrapping on the index finger. It could also be that British English refers to the third finger as "index" rather than the second finger, as in American English (likely a BS assumption, on my part)

Comment: @Noach MiFrankfurt It's not the index finger I'm curious about. It's the way it's wrapped around the finger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim 27:8 [סימן כז - מקום הנחתן ואפן הנחתן](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.27.8?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)  says that one ends the hand strap by wrapping it around the middle finger 3 times and then tying it.

> **ח** אֹרֶךְ רְצוּעָה שֶׁל יָד כְּדֵי שֶׁתַּקִּיף אֶת הַזְּרוֹעַ, וְיִקְשֹׁר מִמֶּנָּה הַקֶּשֶׁר וְתִמָּתַח עַל אֶצְבַּע אֶמְצָעִית, **וְיִכְרֹךְ מִמֶּנָּה עַל אֶצְבָּעוֹ שְׁלֹשָׁה** (יג) **כְּרִיכוֹת, וְיִקְשֹׁר**. וְנוֹהֲגִים הָעוֹלָם לִכְרֹךְ עַל הַזְּרוֹעַ שִׁשָּׁה אוֹ שִׁבְעָה  כְּרִיכוֹת: הגה: וְאֵין לִכְרֹךְ הָרְצוּעָה עַל  הַתִּיתוֹרָא כְּדֵי לְחַזְּקָהּ עַל הַיָּד (מַהֲרִי''ל).‏

Note that the Shulchan Aruch doesn't say where on the finger to wind these 3 times.   He follows the [Tur](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.27.1?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en) who doesn't specify this detail. See the [Bet Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.27.1?lang=bi&p2=Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.27.5.1&lang2=bi) who brings all earlier Rishonim - and nobody specifies this detail, as the Gemara doesn't mention it.

The Be'er Heitev brings the Ari z"l that one should wind once around the middle joint, twice around the bottom joint.

> באר היטב‏
>   **יג**) כריכות. אחד בפרק האמצעי ב' בתחתון. **האר''י ז''ל**: ‏

The Kaf haChaim says the same thing; once around the middle joint, twice around the bottom joint.

> כף החיים על שולחן ערוך אורח חיים כ״ז:לד:א‏
>   לד) [סעיף ח'] **ויכרוך ממנה על אצבעו שלשה כריכות וכו'** היינו שיכרוך על אצבע האמצעי הנקרא אמה ג' כריכות, וכריכה העליונה תהי' בפרק האמצעי של האצבע הזה וב' כריכות תחתונות בפרק התחתון המחובר אל כף היד, כמש"ל סי' כ"ה אות ע' בשם האר"י ז"ל, ועיין שם עוד אות ס"ח;‏

See the Mishna Brura that says 2 on the bottom joint and one on the middle joint, though *some say* first one on the middle joint and then 2 on the bottom joint:

> משנה ברורה כ״ז:ל‏
>   ל) **שלשה כריכות - שנים בפרק התחתון ואחד בפרק האמצעי** וי"א דתחלה א' בפרק אמצעי ואח"כ ב' בפרק התחתון. ואותן הכריכות יעשה אחר הנחת השל ראש:‏

Interestingly enough the Turei Zohov brings the Kavonos Ari z"l and says that for Kabbalistic reasons one should wrap 2 on the bottom and then 1 on the top.

> טורי זהב על שולחן ערוך אורח חיים כ״ז:ח‏
>   **על אצבעו ג' כריכות**. בכוונות האר"י כתו' ששנים מהם יהיו על פירקי התחתון של אצבע והשלישי ע"ג בפרק אמצעי וטעמו ע"ד הקבלה:‏

So there are sources (from the Ari z"l onwards) that "argue" as to whether the custom is to first wind once around the middle joint or to first wind twice around the bottom joint.